# Enable to view the Audit TRACE logs for HBASE Accessconroller

Tags: log4j, hbase, trace, access-control, audit-logging

I have enabled Accesscontrol coprocessor in Hbase for restricting the access, which is working fine.
I tried to log the events of all the users like put,get,scan,drop etc in the audit log by setting up the below configurations in the log4j.properties, But not able to get the TRACE level logs for AccessControl even after setting the below property

```
log4j.logger.SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController=TRACE
```

I can just see the INFO level logs in the "SecurityAuth.audit" file. Please help me to know if i need to set any other properties along with the above. To be more clear attaching the hbase-site.xml file and log4j.properties below.

**hbase-site.xml file**

```
<configuration>
 <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
     <value>true</value>
   </property>

   <property>
  <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
      <name>hbase.superuser</name>
      <value>hadoop</value>
</property>

<property>
     <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.engine</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SecureRpcEngine</value>
</property>
<property>
      <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
      <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.security.exec.permission.checks</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**log4j.properties file**

```
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hbase.root.logger=INFO,console
hbase.security.logger=INFO,console
hbase.log.dir=.
hbase.log.file=hbase.log
hbase.log.level=INFO

# Define the root logger to the system property "hbase.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hbase.root.logger}

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=ALL

#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hbase.log.dir}/${hbase.log.file}

# Rollver at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# 30-day backup
#log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2}: %.1000m%n

# Rolling File Appender properties
hbase.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hbase.log.maxbackupindex=20

# Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hbase.log.dir}/${hbase.log.file}

log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=${hbase.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=${hbase.log.maxbackupindex}

log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2}: %.1000m%n

#
# Security audit appender
hbase.security.log.file=SecurityAuth.audit
hbase.security.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hbase.security.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.RFAS=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAS.File=${hbase.log.dir}/${hbase.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxFileSize=${hbase.security.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxBackupIndex=${hbase.security.log.maxbackupindex}
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %.1000m%n
log4j.category.SecurityLogger=${hbase.security.logger}
log4j.additivity.SecurityLogger=false
log4j.logger.SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController=TRACE
log4j.logger.SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.visibility.VisibilityController=ALL

#
# Null Appender
#
log4j.appender.NullAppender=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender

#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this
#
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2}: %.1000m%n

log4j.appender.asyncconsole=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.AsyncConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.asyncconsole.target=System.err

# Custom Logging levels

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=${hbase.log.level}
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSNamesystem=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase=${hbase.log.level}
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.META=${hbase.log.level}
# Make these two classes INFO-level. Make them DEBUG to see more zk debug.
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil=${hbase.log.level}
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKWatcher=${hbase.log.level}
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.dfs=DEBUG
# Set this class to log INFO only otherwise its OTT
# Enable this to get detailed connection error/retry logging.
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation=TRACE


# Uncomment this line to enable tracing on _every_ RPC call (this can be a lot of output)
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer.trace=DEBUG

# Uncomment the below if you want to remove logging of client region caching'
# and scan of hbase:meta messages
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation=INFO

# EventCounter
# Add "EventCounter" to rootlogger if you want to use this
# Uncomment the line below to add EventCounter information
# log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter

# Prevent metrics subsystem start/stop messages (HBASE-17722)
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSinkAdapter=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl=WARN
```

I have tried by setting the "hbase.security.logger=TRACE,RFAS" too, but no luck. Please help me in case of additional steps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue, with the change in the log4j.propeties file as below

```
#
# Security audit appender
hbase.security.log.file=SecurityAuth.audit
hbase.security.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hbase.security.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.RFAS=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAS.File=${hbase.log.dir}/${hbase.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxFileSize=${hbase.security.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxBackupIndex=${hbase.security.log.maxbackupindex}
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.category.SecurityLogger=TRACE,RFAS
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.additivity.SecurityLogger=false
log4j.logger.SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController=TRACE
log4j.logger.SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.visibility.VisibilityController=TRACE
```